# Finding Directories and files

Tags: unix

```
#for d in $DIRCOUNT
#do
#    DIRCOUNT=$[$DIRCOUNT+1]
#done


#for f in $FILECOUNT
#do
#    FILECOUNT=$[$FILECOUNT+1]
#done

#for r in $READ
#do
#    READ=$[$READ+1]
#done

#for w in $WRITE
#do
#    WRITE=$[$WRITE+1]
#done

#for e in $EXECUTABLE
#do
#    EXECUTE=$[$EXECUTE+1]
#done


for item in $LOCATION/* $LOCATION/.*
do
if  [ -f "$item" ]
 then
    FILECOUNT=$[$FILECOUNT+1]
 elif [ -d "$item" ]
 then
    DIRCOUNT=$[$DIRCOUNT+1]
 elif [ -r "$item" ]
 then
    READ=$[$READ+1]
 elif [ -w "$item" ]
 then
     WRITE=$[$WRITE+1]
 elif [ -e "$item" ]
 then
     EXECUTE=$[$EXECUTE+1]
fi
done

echo "Number of directories: " $DIRCOUNT
echo "Number of files: " $FILECOUNT
echo "Number of readable: " $READ
echo "Number of writble: " $WRITE
echo "Number of executable: " $EXECUTE
```

I want to find out the number of directories and files, and their types. I am new to this, i am not sure what do do with read write and executes. I actually don't know what is happening in the elif part, can someone please explain to me what i have done and what should i be doing?

Comment: A small nit, the `[ -e "$item" ]` should be `[ -x "$item" ]`.  `-e` tests for existence, `-x` for executability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options w.r.t syntax:

```
test -f "$item" && : $((FILECOUNT++))
test -d "$item" && DIRCOUNT=$( expr $DIRCOUNT + 1 )
```

are two that I like.  An else/if chain is probably not appropriate here, since you will never see an increment to READ, WRITE, or EXECUTE, and many files have several of those attributes.

Comment: Sorry can you explain the code you just wrote, sorry i am pretty new with this.

Comment: Using the `&&` as a short-circuiting boolean is a common technique and `cmd && cmd2` is almost equivalent to `if cmd; then cmd2; fi`. (Functionally, they are the same, but `if false; then false; fi` will set `$?` to 0 (that is, it will succeed), but `false && false` will fail and set `$?` to 1.)  This answer is just demonstrating two ways to increment a variable: either `: $((VAR++))` or `VAR=$( expr $VAR + 1)`

Answer (score 0):

The largest problem with your `if-elsif` chain is that the entry's type (e.g., directory, file) is orthogonal to its mode (e.g., read, write, exec).  You should use one chain of `if` statements that detect the entry type and a second set to process the mode.

```
for entry in $LOCATION/* $LOCATION/.*
do
    if [ -d "$entry" ]; then
        DIRCOUNT=$((DIRCOUNT + 1))
    elif [ -f "$entry" ]; then
        FILECOUNT=$((FILECOUNT + 1))
    elif [ -L "$entry" ]; then
        LINKCOUNT=$((LINKCOUNT + 1))
    elif [ -c "$entry" -o -b "$entry" ]; then
        DEVCOUNT=$((DEVCOUNT + 1))
    else
        UNKNOWNCOUNT=$((UNKNOWNCOUNT + 1))
    fi

    if [ -r "$entry" ]; then
        READABLECOUNT=$((READABLECOUNT + 1))
    elif [ -w "$entry" ]; then
        WRITABLECOUNT=$((WRITEABLECOUNT + 1))
    elif [ -x "$entry" ]; then
        ACTIONABLECOUNT=$((ACTIONABLECOUNT + 1))
    fi
end
```

A few things to note:

- there are more types of directory entries than just files and directories.  You also have device files (character & block special) and symbolic links.  If you need to detect FIFOs, then you need to do that *before* the test for "file" (`-f`) since FIFOs are also normal files.  A good reference to [test(1)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) is essential here.
- each entry has a set of associated modes (e.g., read, write, exec, set-uid, set-gid, sticky, etc.).  A good reference to [chmod(1)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/chmod.html) describes these in detail.
- a more UNIX like approach would be to use [find(1)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) and [wc(1)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/wc.html) to count the number of entries that have a particular attribute - `find . -depth 1 -type f | wc -l` will give you the number of "normal files" in the current directory.